# Why would a `#NP` fault expecting an IDT entry at index 302 even be possible?

Tags: rust, x86-64, interrupt, qemu, osdev

Been in the process of writing a [kernel](https://github.com/kennystrawnmusic/cryptos) from scratch in Rust for some time now, and have had it open-sourced since August while attempting to fix some problems related to an AHCI driver write attempt. One problem that I can’t seem to find a solution to at all is this:
[image: Segment selector larger than 256 not present? WTF?]

The IDT is only supposed to be 256 entries long. Why therefore is a handler function expected at entry 302, which is more IDT entries than is legally possible? And how does one go about mapping this properly?

Running QEMU with `-d int` produces this interrupt information:

```
   100: v=97 e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:0000008000021b3c pc=0000008000021b3c SP=0010:fffff00007ffe8f0 env->regs[R_EAX]=000001807eb4a3e0
RAX=000001807eb4a3e0 RBX=0000000000000020 RCX=000fffffffffffff RDX=0000000000000000
RSI=000000000000001f RDI=00000180c1085100 RBP=0000000000000000 RSP=fffff00007ffe8f0
R8 =000000800008bcc8 R9 =0000000000000003 R10=000000007bf36000 R11=0000000000000001
R12=000000000a204000 R13=0000200000c00000 R14=00000180c1085100 R15=fffff00007ffec01
RIP=0000008000021b3c RFL=00000246 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00af9b00 DPL=0 CS64 [-RA]
SS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0020 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0028 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0030 00000080000aed3c 00000067 00008900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000080000aedb8 0000003f
IDT=     00000080000aee30 00000fff
CR0=80010033 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000000002000 CR4=00000668
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=0000000000000020 CCD=0000000000000000 CCO=LOGICL  
EFER=0000000000000d00
check_exception old: 0xffffffff new 0xb

   101: v=0b e=0972 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:0000008000021b3c pc=0000008000021b3c SP=0010:fffff00007ffe8f0 env->regs[R_EAX]=000001807eb4a3e0
RAX=000001807eb4a3e0 RBX=0000000000000020 RCX=000fffffffffffff RDX=0000000000000000
RSI=000000000000001f RDI=00000180c1085100 RBP=0000000000000000 RSP=fffff00007ffe8f0
R8 =000000800008bcc8 R9 =0000000000000003 R10=000000007bf36000 R11=0000000000000001
R12=000000000a204000 R13=0000200000c00000 R14=00000180c1085100 R15=fffff00007ffec01
RIP=0000008000021b3c RFL=00000246 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0018 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00af9b00 DPL=0 CS64 [-RA]
SS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0020 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0028 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0030 00000080000aed3c 00000067 00008900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl
GDT=     00000080000aedb8 0000003f
IDT=     00000080000aee30 00000fff
CR0=80010033 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000000002000 CR4=00000668
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=0000000000000020 CCD=0000000000000000 CCO=LOGICL  
EFER=0000000000000d00
```

Comment: I’m using the `.index()` method on [this API](https://docs.rs/x86_64/latest/x86_64/structures/idt/struct.SelectorErrorCode.html) to (at least in theory) weed out the index from the rest of the selector error code. Not sure if it’s working properly though; trying IDT[60] to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Also to note: the index is 302 decimal, not 0x302.

Comment: Update: nope, setting a handler at IDT[60] made no difference here.

Comment: The code to the `#NP` handler function is [here](https://github.com/kennystrawnmusic/cryptos/blob/4f2772f19ac9be7490cbd34cbc59fb31627a7d09/src/interrupts.rs#L166). Still giving that weird value despite all these careful measures to make sure the code is accurately interpreted.

Comment: Okay ignore what I wrote. In the output that 0x972 was said to be an "index" but that is in fact the selector error code. 0x972 shifted right 3 bits is 0x12E and 0x12E is 302 decimal and that is the selector index.

Comment: Exactly. So then what could possibly be the cause of a `#NP` with a selector index larger than 256? Seems very strange considering that the IDT is never supposed to be that big.

Comment: It looks odd yes. Does the instruction pointer vary (in the output you show is says 0x8000021A7C) or is it always the same location? Since you are using QEMU have you looked at the output while using the `-d int -no-reboot -no-shutdown` options?

Comment: I'd trust the QEMU output more than the info generated by the code in your kernel.

Comment: check_exception old: 0xffffffff new 0xb
   106: v=0b e=0972 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:0000008000021b3c pc=0000008000021b3c SP=0010:fffff00007ffe8f0 env->regs[R_EAX]=000001807eb4a3e0
RAX=000001807eb4a3e0 RBX=0000000000000020 RCX=000fffffffffffff RDX=0000000000000000
RSI=000000000000001f RDI=00000180c1085100 RBP=0000000000000000 RSP=fffff00007ffe8f0
R8 =000000800008bd08 R9 =0000000000000003 R10=000000007bf36000 R11=0000000000000001
R12=000000000a204000 R13=0000200000c00000 R14=00000180c1085100 R15=fffff00007ffec01
RIP=0000008000021b3c and that’s all I can fit here. Full QEMU output is too long.

Comment: And yes, 0x8000021b3c is what the IP is every time.

Comment: Okay so QEMU sees `e=0972`. That is in fact the selector error code (in hex) so you kernel is extracting that properly from the interrupt stack. If it faults at `0008:0000008000021b3c` all the time, what instruction is at 0x0000008000021b3c?

Comment: Technically an IDT in 64-bit can have 4096 entries although the lower 256 are for processor exceptions and external interrupts.

Comment: According to the output of objdump it's this:
     
   21b1f: 74 1b                         je      0x21b3c <_ZN80_$LT$cryptos..ahci..AhciDriver$u20$as$u20$cryptos..pci_impl..PciDeviceHandle$GT$5start17h119149dd68119130E.llvm.17642009288330382129+0xcec>

Problem is, I already have the [PRT](https://github.com/kennystrawnmusic/cryptos/blob/4f2772f19ac9be7490cbd34cbc59fb31627a7d09/src/main.rs#L239) set to route this IRQ properly.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/kennystrawnmusic/cryptos/blob/4f2772f19ac9be7490cbd34cbc59fb31627a7d09/src/ahci/mod.rs#L988) is supposed to be the code that maps the IRQ that said instruction is faulting over.

Comment: Full objdump output: https://pastebin.com/dXWr224H

Comment: Full QEMU output: https://pastebin.com/k0mu9rNR

Comment: Here you go: https://pastebin.com/sH59Tg6M

Comment: Ah, yes, changing the index of the interrupt to 151 worked. Thanks again, documenting as an answer

Answer (score 2):

After a lengthy discussion in the comments on the OP, I finally figured out what the problem was: the IRQ that caused the fault was 0x97 (151). [Re-indexing the AHCI interrupt handler to that specific index in the IDT](https://github.com/kennystrawnmusic/cryptos/commit/391a7c3e1d9dee8366b5ccf57572c7e44ea6a373) solved the problem.

@MichaelPetch has filed a [bug report](https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu/-/issues/1382) against QEMU. QEMU Software emulation encodes the IDT descriptor index incorrectly when running in long mode. QEMU does work when using the `-enable-kvm` option.

As of February 6th 2023 this QEMU bug has had a [patch committed](https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu/-/commit/b585edca34a817fdb751dfe94fbd3cde32ffe60d); accepted; and the bug has been marked closed.

Comment: Edited answer to provide a link to a [bug report](https://github.com/rust-osdev/x86_64/issues/396) that I was filing as you were typing that.

Comment: QEMU software emulation has a bug. I created a disk image that I could run on BOCHS, QEMU, and real hardware. It simulates your problem. I get the correct selector index on real hardware, BOCHS, and QEMU if using the `-enable-kvm` option. If I run QEMU without that option I get the wrong selector encoded. This suggests QEMU software emulation has a bug and improperly encodes the selector using 8 byte scaling rather than 16 byte for IDT index entries.

Comment: In the environments where it works (including real hardware) the selector error code returned is 0x4ba which is selector index 0x97 which is what you'd expect. Software emulation in QEMU is the odd man out that returns 0x972.

Comment: I have put my test code up here: https://github.com/mpetch/SelectorErrorCodeTest . It creates a 1.44MB floppy disk image that can be used on real hardware or an emulator/VM. When it runs it prints the selector error code for Interrupt 0x97 that is marked not present. In an environment where it works it should show 0x4ba . In QEMU using software emulation it shows 0x972

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Unfortunately the development machine I’m working with at the moment is an M1 MacBook Pro so there’s definitely no way to hardware-accelerate the virtualization in that case. Still good to know that you’ve tested it on real hardware and found that it actually works correctly in that case.